# Issue with Creating Application Auto Scaling with AWS Lambda using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm converting some Cloudformation into Terraform that creates a Lambda and then sets up Provisioned Concurrency and Application Auto Scaling for the Lambda.  When Terraform runs the aws_appautoscaling_target resource,  it fails with the following message:

```
Error: Error creating application autoscaling target: ValidationException: Unsupported service namespace, resource type or scalable dimension
```

I haven't found too many examples of the aws_appautoscaling_target resource being used with Lambdas.  Is this no longer supported?  For reference, I'm running Terraform version 1.0.11 and I'm using AWS provider version 3.66.0.  I'm posting my Terraform below.  Thanks.

```
data "archive_file" "foo_create_dist_pkg" {
  source_dir  = var.lambda_file_location
  output_path = "foo.zip"
  type        = "zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "foo" {
  function_name = "foo"
  description   = "foo lambda"
  handler       = "foo.main"
  runtime       = "python3.8"
  publish       = true

  role        = "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:role/serverless-role"
  memory_size = 256
  timeout     = 900

  depends_on       = [data.archive_file.foo_create_dist_pkg]
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.foo_create_dist_pkg.output_base64sha256
  filename         = data.archive_file.foo_create_dist_pkg.output_path
}

resource "aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config" "foo_provisioned_concurrency" {
  function_name                     = aws_lambda_function.foo.function_name
  provisioned_concurrent_executions = 15
  qualifier                         = aws_lambda_function.foo.version
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "autoscale_foo" {
  max_capacity       = var.PCMax
  min_capacity       = var.PCMin
  resource_id        = "function:${aws_lambda_function.foo.function_name}"
  scalable_dimension = "lambda:function:ProvisionedConcurrency"
  service_namespace  = "lambda"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to publish your Lambda to get a new version. This can be done by setting `publish = true` in `aws_lambda_function` resource. This will give a numeric version for your function which can be used in the `aws_appautoscaling_target`:

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "autoscale_foo" {
  max_capacity       = var.PCMax
  min_capacity       = var.PCMin
  resource_id        = "function:${aws_lambda_function.foo.function_name}:${aws_lambda_function.foo.version}"
  scalable_dimension = "lambda:function:ProvisionedConcurrency"
  service_namespace  = "lambda"
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an [`aws_lambda_alias`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_alias) and use that in the `aws_appautoscaling_target` instead of the Lambda version. Nevertheless, this would require also the function to be published.