# Issue with AWS Lambda Alias and Provisioned Concurrency

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

This feeds off of question: [Issue with Creating Application Auto Scaling with AWS Lambda using Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70040765/issue-with-creating-application-auto-scaling-with-aws-lambda-using-terraform)

I put a Lambda Alias in my terraform that I'm going to use in my Provisioned Concurrency Config.  I get the following error during the aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config resource creation:

```
Error: error getting Lambda Provisioned Concurrency Config (arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<AWS-ACCOUNT-#>:function:foo:PC): ValidationException: status code: 400, request id: 82c5e589-d455-4d53-abea-bac8e5b5a2ea
```

My terraform is below:

```
resource "aws_lambda_alias" "foo_pc" {
  name             = "PC"
  description      = "foo PC Alias"
  function_name    = aws_lambda_function.foo.arn
  function_version = aws_lambda_function.foo.version
}

resource "aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config" "foo_provisioned_concurrency" {
  function_name                     = aws_lambda_alias.foo_pc.function_name
  provisioned_concurrent_executions = var.PCInit
  qualifier                         = aws_lambda_alias.foo_pc.name
}
```

I want the alias to point to the latest deployment of the lambda. Can I not use in my aws_lambda_function.foo.version in my lambda alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/APIReference/API_RegisterScalableTarget.html#API_RegisterScalableTarget_RequestParameters), in case Lambda provisioned concurrency auto-scaling:

> Lambda provisioned concurrency - The resource type is function and the unique identifier is the function name with a function version or alias name suffix that is not `$LATEST`. Example: `function:my-function:prod` or `function:my-function:1`.

In case of an alias, the resource id should look something like this:

```
resource_id = "function:${aws_lambda_function.foo.name}:${aws_lambda_alias.foo_pc.name}"
```

**Update for the error message:**

There is an open issue reported for the provider in GitHub: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/12923

Comment: The issue is not with the aws_appautoscaling_target but with the aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config.  It keeps failing on that resource with  the error I reported above.

Comment: I see, there is a reported bug for that one. You may want to try some workarounds from Github. I cannot confirm which one would work.